# How do you say "When I was in high school I took (guitar) lessons"

Tags: translation

How do you say this in Japanese?

> When I was in high school I took (guitar) lessons.

I don't know the proper word for 'lessons' or which verb goes with it. Of course I would appreciate a translation of the whole sentence though.

My best guess would be:

> Watashi wa koko no toki ni ressun o torimashita

Comment: What's the sentence you came up with so far ?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799) on meta.

Comment: My best guess would be: Watashi wa  koko no toki ni ressun o torimashita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best verb is **[習]{なら}う**. Check the dictionary on [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%BF%92%E3%81%86):

> to take lessons in; to be taught; to learn (from a teacher); to study (under a teacher); to get training in

The point of the verb 習う is that you have a teacher.

So the whole sentence is:

> [私]{わたし}は[高校]{こうこう}のときギターを[習]{なら}っていました。
>
> Watashi wa kōkō no toki gitā o naratte imashita.

---

Using the verb [習]{なら}う, it is difficult to hide "guitar" and just say "took some lessons." In this case, the noun [習]{なら}い[事]{ごと} is suitable. This means "(taking) lessons".

> [私]{わたし}は[高校]{こうこう}のとき[習]{なら}い[事]{ごと}をしていました。
>
> Watashi wa kōkō no toki naraigoto o shite imashita.

---

Side Note: in some cases you can use [取]{と}る to mean "take (classes)". It has the nuance of choosing from many classes and used often in universities where students can choose what classes they take.

Answer (score 1):

ressun is ok, but you might want to consider jugyou.
And also using ukemashita instead of torimashita.

> 高校の時、ギターの授業を受けました。
>   こうこうのとき、ぎたーのじゅぎょうをうけました。
>   koukou no toki, gitaa no jugyou wo ukemashita.